# You Tube player stopping abruptly just after starting when scrolling my feedwall

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

In my android app I have a feedwall for images, gifs and videos.For playing videos I am making use of Android YouTube api which plays videos from YouTube links(URLs). The feedwall is a listview which makes use of a Base Adapter. For videos I am using a FrameLayout which is contained inside a RelativeLayout as below

```
             <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/feedVideoRelLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

I am casting this Framelayout as a YouTubePlayerSupportFragment as below

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerLayout;

 viewHolder.youTubePlayerLayout = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) activityRef.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youTubePlayerLayout);
```

Now for playing videos in my feedwall,inside the getView method of the adapter I am using

```
 viewHolder.youTubePlayerLayout = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction;

            transaction = activityRef.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youTubePlayerLayout, viewHolder.youTubePlayerLayout).commit();
            viewHolder.youTubePlayerLayout.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                    if (!wasRestored) {
                        player.loadVideo(Utils.getYouTubeVideoIdFromUrl(feedModelArrayList.get(position).getPostMediaURL()));
                        player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                        player.play();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                    String errorMessage = arg0.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(activityRef, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);

                }
            });
```

In my feedwall whenever a video link is detected the video starts playing in the YouTube player.Now the problem is, this happens only for the first time.
After scrolling down if again a video link is detected the player loads the video but stops immediately after playing, within a second. Secondly, the first video feed which played successfully also behaves same, even after tapping the play button.

In the logcat I get the warnings like

```
 W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.FrameLayout{d56f6d9 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 (these should all be positive).
```

I went through all the threads related to this warning on SO but unfortunately none of them were useful.

Comment: Instead of using `transaction.add(R.id.youTubePlayerLayout,....)` use `transaction.replace(R.id.youTubePlayerLayout,....)`, the reason behind this i think is the viewholder reusage.

Comment: @AB this also I had tried. In this case what happens is for the first time the video player loads with the video and plays. But for the second views,after scrolling the view itself doesn't load. Any suggestions ?

Comment: are you getting the same warning?

Comment: @AB yupp..I am still getting that warning